# Why i sometimes got error and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

This code is supposed to get random JSON data from an array when the user clicks the button. I'm using a function to return a random number. But when I load the page and click on the button, sometimes I get random data, while sometimes I get an error.

[image]

Why is this? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
        
    function renderQuiz() {
        console.log(userdata.USER.TOPSONGS[(getRandomInt(0,2))][(getRandomInt(0,4))].snippet);     
    }
    
    ...

    $('#button').click(function () {
        renderQuiz();
        console.log("userprogress: " + userprogress);

        if (userprogress < 10) {
            userprogress++;
            $('#answered').text(`${userprogress} / 10`);
        } 
        else { window.location.href = '/result'; }
        return;
    });

}); //end document.ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `userdata.USER.TOPSONGS` contain a 3x5 array in which all values are defined and all values have a `.snippet`?

Mostly probably, `userdata.USER.TOPSONGS` does not contain `[x][y].snippet` for some values `0 <= x <= 2` and `0 <= y <= 4`, causing this error.

Please check your `userdata.USER.TOPSONGS` array and/or adjust the minimum and maximum values being passed to the random number function.

Comment: yeah, it's out of bound. silly mistakes i made,i should be more meticulous after this. tq for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like reaching out of the boundaries of the array. Your `getRandomInt(min, max)` returns random int including `min` and `max` values. Check if this is okay.